# Cygwin and imagemagick

Tags: shell, cygwin, imagemagick, bash

Its been 15 years since I used Unix ksh shell, bash now.  It's coming back to me but I spent a lot of time trying to get the basic interactive shell to not only like my scripts and syntax,  I read man pages on setting up .bashrc and such but nothing.

example: I could not source anything till i took out all the "." chars in function names and file names, still could not get the functions and vars to load from a sourced script back to the caller... and then finally.... discovered the problem was using   " 2>&1 $LOGFILE"  on my calls when sourceing.  go figure. days wasted.

I now have bash kinda working enough to try to install image magick 6.8.8 but its not working either.   I followed the instructions for installing, expanded the tar ball, set the env var, added to path before all others.  like the source issue i had the shell finds the IM commands,  in the right folder and runs them, they just dont do anything.  all i get is a CR/LF when entering any IM exe.

Thats why i am asking now, seems like some flag I am not setting..

do I need to register the dlls?  why are they .exe files?

What am I forgetting to do?
Also do you have any good default settings or tips on setting up bash shell to  work with and debug lots of bash

GNU bash, version 4.3.42(4)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)
cygwin64 on Windows7."
ImageMagick-6.8.8

here is the relevant part of the env...

```
    $ ls -l convert.exe compare.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Administrators None 74892 Jan 27  2014 compare.exe
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Administrators None 74316 Jan 27  2014 convert.exe
$ which convert
/home/ripple/ImageMagick-6.8.8/bin/convert


ripple@prp-lap-tos ~
$ convert.exe -version
convert.exe -version

ripple@prp-lap-tos ~

========================================

 ============================    
    $ **env**
    HOMEPATH=\Users\ripple
    ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
    HOSTNAME=prp-lap-tos
    SHELL=/bin/bash
    TERM=xterm
    PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=AMD64 Family 15 Model 104 Stepping 2, AuthenticAMD
    PROFILEREAD=true oRIGINAL_PATH=/cygdrive/c/bin:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows
    USER=ripple
    !::=::\
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ripple/ImageMagick-6.8.8/lib
    USERNAME=ripple
    PROCESSOR_LEVEL=15
    PATH=/home/ripple/bin:/home/ripple/ImageMagick6.8.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/bin:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows

    PSModulePath=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
    FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
    PWD=/home/ripple/ImageMagick-6.8.8/bin
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    TZ=America/Denver
    PS1=\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$
    MAGICK_HOME=/home/ripple/ImageMagick-6.8.8
    PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
    EXECIGNORE=*.dll
    SHLVL=1
    HOME=/home/ripple
    INFOPATH=/usr/local/info:/usr/share/info:/usr/info
    _=/usr/bin/env
==================================


from .**bashrc**
 export MAGICK_HOME="$HOME/ImageMagick-6.8.8"
 export PATH="$MAGICK_HOME"/bin:$PATH
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:}"$MAGICK_HOME/lib
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

==================================================

$ **shopt**
autocd          off
cdable_vars     on
cdspell         on
checkhash       on
checkjobs       off
checkwinsize    on
cmdhist         on
compat31        off
compat32        off
compat40        off
compat41        off
compat42        off
completion_strip_exe    off
complete_fullquote      on
direxpand       off
dirspell        off
dotglob         off
execfail        off
expand_aliases  on
extdebug        off
extglob         on
extquote        on
failglob        off
force_fignore   on
globstar        off
globasciiranges off
gnu_errfmt      off
histappend      on
histreedit      on
histverify      on
hostcomplete    on
huponexit       off
interactive_comments    on
lastpipe        off
lithist         off
login_shell     on
mailwarn        off
no_empty_cmd_completion on
nocaseglob      on
nocasematch     off
nullglob        off
progcomp        on
promptvars      on
restricted_shell        off
shift_verbose   off
sourcepath      on
xpg_echo        off


scripts 

!#/bin/bash -x 
which does not seem to work right either, its not echoing like I thought. 

been playing with these commands too.
#set +n 
#set +C
#set -o posix
#set -euo pipefail
```

thanks,

Ripple Ratt

Phat Ratt Photography

Comment: You can install imagemagick without cygwin at all..

Comment: It doesn't sound like you installed ImageMagick via Cygwin, it sounds like you installed a non-Cygwin version.  Uninstall IM however you did it, run Cygwin's setup program again, and choose ImageMagick.  Then try again.  It should just work out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to install **imagemagick** on Windows, consider the [**chocolatey** package manager](https://chocolatey.org/).

[ImageMagick 6.9.3.7 is available](https://chocolatey.org/packages/imagemagick), so after installing **chocolatey**, one would run:

```
choco install imagemagick
```